# C# Extending property with custom function

Tags: c#

How can I extend the .text and .caption property of ALL controls. I want to create a multilanguage App, which load the text from a custom file.

I want to do this:

```
button1.Text.LoadLocalizedText()
label1.Caption.LoadLocalizedText()
```

Now, I need the following text result, to get the correct text.
I need  "class.button1.Text" as string and for the label "class.label1.Caption" as string.

After I load the custom text, I must set the text dynamically to the "source" property like text or caption.

I hope, someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: rather something like `Utils.LoadLocalizedText(() => button1.Text)` with Expressions

Comment: You could write your own control classes that derive from `Button` and `Label` and so on. Then, instead of extension methods, you could write your custom localizer function inside these classes.

Comment: You can't extend a property like Text. Text returns a string type, if you were going to add methods like this you would have to create a custom control for your buttons and labels that use a custom string type to include this method. .NET already has functionality to handle localization. I would look into that instead of trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF?

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for answer.. i will have a look

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EtObTV but you will need also pass some control instance

Comment: @Adriani6 Winforms

Comment: @DJNoeppes See answer below then.

Comment: @Selvin GREAT!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a method you can call on all controls, write a extension method for control (see @Adriani6's answer)

```
public static void LoadLocalizedText(this Control ctrl) {...}
```

If you want to load a resource localized by your culture, you should use your resource files and create files for each culture.
Create 2 resource files like `Resource1.resx` and `Resource1.de.resx` and save your corresponding values to the resource files.
Then, you can load your resources like

```
[ProjectNamespace.]Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("myResource");
```

or, alternatively with an overload to specify the culture yourself

```
Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("myResource", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de"));
```

[See Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstring?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

If this is WinForms, you can write an extension method for the `Control` class.

```
public static class LocalizationExtension
{
    public static void LoadLocalizedText(this Control ctrl)
    {
        ctrl.Text = "My loaded string";
    }

}
```

This way you can target all controls that inherit from Control such as Button and Label.

You just call it using `Button.LoadLocalizedText()` and `Label.LocdLocalizedText()` etc..